# Testing if JS Variable is set as a function parameter

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to test if a javascript variable is passed a value into a function

```
function test(a, b) {  /* check if b was given a value */ }
```

I want to say

```
if(!b)
```

but this doesn't work if `b = 0`. Do I have to individually check if it is undefined or null like

```
if(typeof(b) === 'undefined' || b === null)
```

or is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 2):

you can check the arguments property

```
if(arguments.length > 1){ //is there a 'b' argument
 //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply check for undefined:

```
if (b === undefined)
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp